# Reverse Bootstrap's breakpoint effect

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

Using bootstrap, with this sample :

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-4"></div>
    <div class="col-md-4"></div>
    <div class="col-md-4"></div>
</div>
```

After passing the breakpoint of 768px your cols will go from a vertical alignment to an horizontal alignment. How can I reverse this effect ? I need my cols to start horizontal then go vertical after the breakpoint.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just add `col-md-12` (breakpoint of 768px or higher will be full width).
Then, add `col-4` as well, that will affect from this breakpoint down.

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-4 col-md-12"></div>
    <div class="col-4 col-md-12"></div>
    <div class="col-4 col-md-12"></div>
</div>
```

You can see more in the Bootstrap [documentation](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/layout/grid/) how this grid system works.